# The lowest value of a for which the limit of $f\left(x\right)=2\int _0^x\frac{1}{\left(t^2+1\right)^a}dt$, as $x$ approaches infinity, is finite!

Tags: integration, limits

> $$f\left(x\right)=2\int _0^x\frac{1}{\left(t^2+1\right)^a}dt$$

What is the lowest value of a in the above integral for which the limit of $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches infinity, is finite?

A less important question: What are values of a where $f(x)$ approaches interesting values, such as $\tau$? What about interesting values of $a$, such as $\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$ or $1-\frac1e$?

Notes: when $a$ is $1$, $f(x)$ approaches $\pi$. When $a$ is $0$, $f(x)$ always grows at a linear rate. When $a$ is $0.5$, $f(x)$ always grows logarithmically.

Comment: There is no least value. The improper integral converges for $a > 1/2$ and diverges for $a \le 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Near $+\infty $,

$$\frac {1}{(t^2+1)^a}\sim \frac {1}{ t^{2a} }$$

the limit of the integral exists if $$2a>1$$

or $$a>\frac {1}{2}. $$

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I had just been experimenting on a calculator when I came across this.